# Aligning all the elements of HTML withing the same line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image(My Output for Tablet Version):[image: My Output Image for Tablet Version]

I want to align the third element of HTML within the same line.

The third box when floated into the next line does not aligning itself correctly in the next line as you can see in the image above

Kindly let me know the error in my code .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

p {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: gray;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

div.Chicken {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 2px 37px 5px 37px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
}

div.Beef {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 2px 37px 5px 37px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
}

div.Sushi {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2px 37px 5px 37px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 0px;
  width: 110px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Desktop Version*/

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.67%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 90%;
  }
}


/*Tablet Version*/

@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.67%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
}


/*Mobile Version*/

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.67%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Module 2 Assignment Coursera</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="Chicken">Chicken</div>
    <p>

      The font-family property specifies a list of fontss, from highest priority to lowest. Font selection does not simply stop at the first font in the list that is on the user's system. Rather, font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an
      available font does not have a glyph for a needed character, the latter fonts are tried. (However, this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6 or earlier.)
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="Beef">Beef</div>
    <p>
      The font-family property specifies a list of fonts, from highest priority to lowest. Font selection does not simply stop at the first font in the list that is on the user's system. Rather, font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an
      available font does not have a glyph for a needed character, the latter fonts are tried. (However, this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6 or earlier.)
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="Sushi">Sushi</div>
    <p>

      The font-family property specifies a list of fonts, from highest priority to lowest. Font selection does not simply stop at the first font in the list that is on the user's system. Rather, font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an
      available font does not have a glyph for a needed character, the latter fonts are tried. (However, this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6 or earlier.)
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the output similar as shown below in which all the elements are aligned perfectly.

Expected Image for Tablet Version:[image: Expected Image for Tablet Version]

Thank you for your concern in advance.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using width use margin-left and margin-right. Change p to:

```
p {
    font-family: monospace;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Then you also have to change the right in div.sushi, div.Beef and div.Chicken to put the label in the right top corner:

```
div.Sushi, div.Chicken, div.Beef {
    padding: 2px 37px 5px 37px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 0px;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer . It worked . Could you please tell me that how we can use the percentage to define the width and still it shows the expected image.